# Email validation

Tags: code-golf, string, decision-problem

Write a function or program to validate an e-mail address against RFC [5321](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5321) (some grammar rules found in [5322](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5322)) with the relaxation that you can ignore comments and folding whitespace (`CFWS`) and generalised address literals. This gives the grammar

```
Mailbox              = Local-part "@" ( Domain / address-literal )

Local-part           = Dot-string / Quoted-string
Dot-string           = Atom *("."  Atom)
Atom                 = 1*atext
atext                = ALPHA / DIGIT /    ; Printable US-ASCII
                       "!" / "#" /        ;  characters not including
                       "$" / "%" /        ;  specials.  Used for atoms.
                       "&" / "'" /
                       "*" / "+" /
                       "-" / "/" /
                       "=" / "?" /
                       "^" / "_" /
                       "`" / "{" /
                       "|" / "}" /
                       "~"
Quoted-string        = DQUOTE *QcontentSMTP DQUOTE
QcontentSMTP         = qtextSMTP / quoted-pairSMTP
qtextSMTP            = %d32-33 / %d35-91 / %d93-126
quoted-pairSMTP      = %d92 %d32-126

Domain               = sub-domain *("." sub-domain)
sub-domain           = Let-dig [Ldh-str]
Let-dig              = ALPHA / DIGIT
Ldh-str              = *( ALPHA / DIGIT / "-" ) Let-dig

address-literal      = "[" ( IPv4-address-literal / IPv6-address-literal ) "]"
IPv4-address-literal = Snum 3("."  Snum)
IPv6-address-literal = "IPv6:" IPv6-addr
Snum                 = 1*3DIGIT
                       ; representing a decimal integer value in the range 0 through 255
```

Note: I've skipped the definition of `IPv6-addr` because this particular RFC gets it wrong and disallows e.g. `::1`. The correct spec is in [RFC 2373](http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc2373.txt).

#### Restrictions

You may not use any existing e-mail validation library calls. However, you may use existing network libraries to check IP addresses.

If you write a function/method/operator/equivalent it should take a string and return a boolean or truthy/falsy value, as appropriate for your language. If you write a program it should take a single line from stdin and indicate valid or invalid via the exit code.

#### Test cases

The following test cases are listed in blocks for compactness. The first block are cases which should pass:

```
email@domain.com
e@domain.com
firstname.lastname@domain.com
email@subdomain.domain.com
firstname+lastname@domain.com
email@123.123.123.123
email@[123.123.123.123]
"email"@domain.com
1234567890@domain.com
email@domain-one.com
_______@domain.com
email@domain.name
email@domain.co.jp
firstname-lastname@domain.com
""@domain.com
"e"@domain.com
"\@"@domain.com
email@domain
"Abc\@def"@example.com
"Fred Bloggs"@example.com
"Joe\\Blow"@example.com
"Abc@def"@example.com
customer/department=shipping@example.com
$A12345@example.com
!def!xyz%abc@example.com
_somename@example.com
_somename@[IPv6:::1]
fred+bloggs@abc.museum
email@d.com
?????@domain.com
```

The following test cases should not pass:

```
plainaddress
#@%^%#$@#$@#.com
@domain.com
Joe Smith <email@domain.com>
email.domain.com
email@domain@domain.com
.email@domain.com
email.@domain.com
email.email.@domain.com
email..email@domain.com
email@domain.com (Joe Smith)
email@-domain.com
email@domain..com
email@[IPv6:127.0.0.1]
email@[127.0.0]
email@[.127.0.0.1]
email@[127.0.0.1.]
email@IPv6:::1]
_somename@domain.com]
email@[256.123.123.123]
```

Comment: since `IPv6-addr` has been left undefined, and there are test cases that have ipv6 addresses, is there a correct way to validate them?

Comment: Why should `email@d.com` and `?????@domain.com` fail?

Comment: @ardnew, I've added a link to the relevant RFC. I don't want to inline it because the question is already quite long.

Comment: @grc, good question. I've checked them, because no-one raised this during the several months that the question was in the [sandbox](http://meta.codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/537/194), but I can't see why they should fail so I've moved them to the "Pass" side.

Comment: Are length limits required as well? 254 for entire email address/64 for local-part/63 for each domain label?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### Python 3.3, 261

```
import re,ipaddress
try:v,p=re.match(r'^(?!\.)(((^|\.)[\w!#-\'*+\-/=?^-~]+)+|"([ !#-[\]-~]|\\[ -~])*")@(((?!-)[a-zA-Z\d-]+(?<!-)($|\.))+|\[(IPv6:)?(.*)\])(?<!\.)$',input()).groups()[7:];exec("if p:ipaddress.IPv%dAddress(p)"%(v and 6or 4))
except:v=5
print(v!=5)
```

Python 3.3 is needed for the ipaddress module, which is used to validate IPv4 and IPv6 addresses.

Less golfed version:

```
import re, ipaddress

dot_string = r'(?!\.)((^|\.)[\w!#-\'*+\-/=?^-~]+)+'
    # negative lookahead to check that string doesn't start with .
    # each atom must start with a . or the beginning of the string

quoted_string = r'"([ !#-[\]-~]|\\[ -~])*"'
    # - is used for character ranges (also in dot_string)

domain = r'((?!-)[a-zA-Z\d-]+(?<!-)($|\.))+(?<!\.)'
    # negative lookahead/lookbehind to check each subdomain doesn't start/end with -
    # each domain must end with a . or the end of the string
    # negative lookbehind to check that string doesn't end with .

address_literal = r'\[(IPv6:)?(.*)\]'
    # captures the is_IPv6 and ip_address groups

final_regex = r'^(%s|%s)@(%s|%s)$' % (dot_string, quoted_string, domain, address_literal)

try:
    is_IPv6, ip_address = re.match(final_regex, input(), re.VERBOSE).groups()[7:]
        # if input doesn't match, calling .groups() will throw an exception

    if ip_address:
        exec("ipaddress.IPv%dAddress(ip_address)" % (6 if is_IPv6 else 4))
            # IPv4Address or IPv6Address will throw an exception if ip_address isn't valid
except:
    is_IPv6 = 5

print(is_IPv6 != 5)
    # is_IPv6 is used as a flag to tell whether an exception was thrown
```

Comment: very nice. i can't immediately find any duplicate patterns (to replace with a shorter variable identifier). but it looks like `ALPHA` in augmented BNF and the char literals constructing a `Quoted-string` are all case-insensitive. can you shave a few chars by specifying case-insensitivity and ditching one of those char class ranges? btw, if you're feeling frisky, can you give a short description of how you developed this?

Comment: @ardnew: Thanks. I've added a less golfed version with a few comments trying to explain some of the trickier parts. I developed the regex in four individual pieces (dot-string, quoted-string, domain and address-literal), then merged them together and added the ip validation. Needless to say, golfing it got really messy.

Comment: No length limits?

Answer (score 2):

PHP 5.4.9, 495

```
function _($e){return preg_match('/^(?!(?>"?(?>\\\[ -~]|[^"])"?){255,})(?!"?(?>\\\[ -~]|[^"]){65,}"?@)(?>([!#-\'*+\/-9=?^-~-]+)(?>\.(?1))*|"(?>[ !#-\[\]-~]|\\\[ -~])*")@(?!.*[^.]{64,})(?>([a-z0-9](?>[a-z0-9-]*[a-z0-9])?)(?>\.(?2)){0,126}|\[(?:(?>IPv6:(?>([a-f0-9]{1,4})(?>:(?3)){7}|(?!(?:.*[a-f0-9][:\]]){8,})((?3)(?>:(?3)){0,6})?::(?4)?))|(?>(?>IPv6:(?>(?3)(?>:(?3)){5}:|(?!(?:.*[a-f0-9]:){6,})(?5)?::(?>((?3)(?>:(?3)){0,4}):)?))?(25[0-5]|2[0-4]\d|1\d{2}|[1-9]?\d)(?>\.(?6)){3}))\])$/iD', $e);}
```

And just for further interest, here's one for RFC 5322 grammar which allows for nested CFWS and obsolete local-parts:

(764)

```
function _($e){return preg_match('/^(?!(?>(?1)"?(?>\\\[ -~]|[^"])"?(?1)){255,})(?!(?>(?1)"?(?>\\\[ -~]|[^"])"?(?1)){65,}@)((?>(?>(?>((?>(?>(?>\x0D\x0A)?[\t ])+|(?>[\t ]*\x0D\x0A)?[\t ]+)?)(\((?>(?2)(?>[\x01-\x08\x0B\x0C\x0E-\'*-\[\]-\x7F]|\\\[\x00-\x7F]|(?3)))*(?2)\)))+(?2))|(?2))?)([!#-\'*+\/-9=?^-~-]+|"(?>(?2)(?>[\x01-\x08\x0B\x0C\x0E-!#-\[\]-\x7F]|\\\[\x00-\x7F]))*(?2)")(?>(?1)\.(?1)(?4))*(?1)@(?!(?1)[a-z\d-]{64,})(?1)(?>([a-z\d](?>[a-z\d-]*[a-z\d])?)(?>(?1)\.(?!(?1)[a-z\d-]{64,})(?1)(?5)){0,126}|\[(?:(?>IPv6:(?>([a-f\d]{1,4})(?>:(?6)){7}|(?!(?:.*[a-f\d][:\]]){8,})((?6)(?>:(?6)){0,6})?::(?7)?))|(?>(?>IPv6:(?>(?6)(?>:(?6)){5}:|(?!(?:.*[a-f\d]:){6,})(?8)?::(?>((?6)(?>:(?6)){0,4}):)?))?(25[0-5]|2[0-4]\d|1\d{2}|[1-9]?\d)(?>\.(?9)){3}))\])(?1)$/isD', $e);}
```

And if length-limits are not a requirement:

**RFC 5321** (414)

```
function _($e){return preg_match('/^(?>([!#-\'*+\/-9=?^-~-]+)(?>\.(?1))*|"(?>[ !#-\[\]-~]|\\\[ -~])*")@(?>([a-z0-9](?>[a-z0-9-]*[a-z0-9])?)(?>\.(?2)){0,126}|\[(?:(?>IPv6:(?>([a-f0-9]{1,4})(?>:(?3)){7}|(?!(?:.*[a-f0-9][:\]]){8,})((?3)(?>:(?3)){0,6})?::(?4)?))|(?>(?>IPv6:(?>(?3)(?>:(?3)){5}:|(?!(?:.*[a-f0-9]:){6,})(?5)?::(?>((?3)(?>:(?3)){0,4}):)?))?(25[0-5]|2[0-4]\d|1\d{2}|[1-9]?\d)(?>\.(?6)){3}))\])$/iD', $e);}
```

**RFC 5322** (636)

```
function _($e){return preg_match('/^((?>(?>(?>((?>(?>(?>\x0D\x0A)?[\t ])+|(?>[\t ]*\x0D\x0A)?[\t ]+)?)(\((?>(?2)(?>[\x01-\x08\x0B\x0C\x0E-\'*-\[\]-\x7F]|\\\[\x00-\x7F]|(?3)))*(?2)\)))+(?2))|(?2))?)([!#-\'*+\/-9=?^-~-]+|"(?>(?2)(?>[\x01-\x08\x0B\x0C\x0E-!#-\[\]-\x7F]|\\\[\x00-\x7F]))*(?2)")(?>(?1)\.(?1)(?4))*(?1)@(?1)(?>([a-z\d](?>[a-z\d-]*[a-z\d])?)(?>(?1)\.(?1)(?5)){0,126}|\[(?:(?>IPv6:(?>([a-f\d]{1,4})(?>:(?6)){7}|(?!(?:.*[a-f\d][:\]]){8,})((?6)(?>:(?6)){0,6})?::(?7)?))|(?>(?>IPv6:(?>(?6)(?>:(?6)){5}:|(?!(?:.*[a-f\d]:){6,})(?8)?::(?>((?6)(?>:(?6)){0,4}):)?))?(25[0-5]|2[0-4]\d|1\d{2}|[1-9]?\d)(?>\.(?9)){3}))\])(?1)$/isD', $e);}
```